# Filtering SharePoint List by Another SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint, filter, web-parts

I posted this question on Stack Exchange here: (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/249418/filtering-sharepoint-list-by-another-sharepoint-list), but just realized I should have posted it to Stack Overflow instead. Hope it's not bad form to cross-post (I'll add a link to this post in the other post).

I've been searching the forums and doing research online with no luck- apologies if this has been answered before.

I have a list with several thousand items in it. I often receive bulk update requests where I need to update several hundred of these items at a time (let's say for this example that we're using a field called "Case ID").

Here's what I've tried:

- Searching cases individually, or up to three at a time in datasheet view; this is not time effective
- Exporting the list and manually manipulating the data in Excel, then pasting in (and writing over) the data in the column that needs to be updated; this approach is not user friendly, is not necessarily time effective, and has potential side effects (causing errors for users currently modifying items that I am changing in bulk)
- Lastly- I know I can create custom views that isolate this data; the problem is that the lists of cases I need to modify generally do not have enough commonalities to isolate them using the view filter logic

So- my guess is that I need two lists, likely connected with a web part. The first list would exist solely for the purpose of querying the second list. I would enter the Case IDs I wanted to filter by in the first list, and the second list would filter to show only the Case IDs in the first list. All items would be deleted from the first list between queries.

I'm not married to this approach- it's just my best guess. I'm open to creative and alternative approached, but the final process needs to be user friendly (business partners will be using it).

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? I've tried to get something implemented several times over the past few years and have never been successful; posting here is my last resort before I throw in the towel.

I have SP 2013, and have SharePoint Designer; please let me know if I need to add any other information.

Thanks in advance for the support,

Chad

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to create a JSOM application that will do all updates. It can query only items for update and do item-by-item update.

Comment: I'm open to this, but it may be too far outside my comfort zone (for now). Do you know of any rough guide or straw-man build I can reference? Not looking to get the work done for me, just trying to figure out where to start.

Comment: @Chad, you can look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-javascript-library-code-in-sharepoint#sharepoint-list-item-tasks Basically you need to query information from two lists, match items from one and another and run update for matching ones. Application can be done as html file in Assets library and visualized with Content Editor web-part